# Help creating a query to pull all email data from MC into a DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, query, data-views

I want to pull my email data from MC into Market Intelligence (Datorama) by subscriber ID and include enterprise attributes.  The best way I have found thus far is to create a DE with the needed info and use the MC Data Extension API in Datorama to ingest.  I need a query that will create a daily file of email activity in MC.  I have tried the following, but it does not pull all the information.  For testing purposes I limited the query to two emailnames as seen in the Where statement.  If I run this query for just one of the emailnames at a time I get the correct numbers of Opens, Sends and clicks. (comparing it to a report pulled from MC).  When I run the query with both email names one email has the correct number of opens, send, clicks, but the other has a much lower number than it should.  Why is the query not pulling the correct numbers for both emails?

```
Select
s.SubscriberID, 
s.SubscriberKey,
s.jobid,
s.eventdate as SentDate,
j.emailname,
o.eventdate as OpenDate,
c.eventdate as ClickDate,
c.linkname as LinkName
From 
_sent s
Left Join _job j on s.jobid = j.jobid
Left Join _Open o on s.jobid =o.jobid
            AND  s.subscriberid = o.subscriberid
             AND s.ListID = o.ListID 
             and s.BatchID = o.BatchID 
             AND o.ISUnique = 1
Left Join _click c on s.jobid = c.jobid
             AND s.ListID = o.ListID 
             and s.BatchID = o.BatchID 
             and s.subscriberid = c.subscriberid
             AND c.ISUnique = 1
Where emailname IN ('IC_InsiderToday_Employee_28-Oct-2022_Null_Null_Null','IC_InsiderToday_Employee_28-Nov-2022_Null_Null_Null')
```

Comment: Maybe create the individual DEs for Send, Open and Click and check the counts before joining them all together?

Comment: @Karen when you said it was incorrect, Which one were you comparing to the records in 2 SQL queries or the metric (opens, sends, clicks) from the MC report?

Comment: Thank you all for replying, I ended up creating the send, open and click data in different queries and them combining with a separate query,  It works.

Answer (score 0):

The join condition for _Click seems not correct: ListID and BatchID

```
Select
s.SubscriberID, 
s.SubscriberKey,
s.jobid,
s.eventdate as SentDate,
j.emailname,
o.eventdate as OpenDate,
c.eventdate as ClickDate,
c.linkname as LinkName
From 
_sent s
Left Join _job j on s.jobid = j.jobid
Left Join _Open o on s.jobid =o.jobid
            AND  s.subscriberid = o.subscriberid
             AND s.ListID = o.ListID 
             and s.BatchID = o.BatchID 
             AND o.ISUnique = 1
Left Join _click c on s.jobid = c.jobid
             AND s.ListID = c.ListID 
             and s.BatchID = c.BatchID 
             and s.subscriberid = c.subscriberid
             AND c.ISUnique = 1
Where emailname IN ('IC_InsiderToday_Employee_28-Oct-2022_Null_Null_Null','IC_InsiderToday_Employee_28-Nov-2022_Null_Null_Null')
```

Comment: What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: @KarenMcRight The alias for Click data view was wrong. It was o.ListID and o.BatchID. I changed them to c.ListID and c.BatchID. Can you run and check if the counts are correct?